# HypergraphDB Netbeans settings

Tags: java, netbeans, nosql, berkeley-db

I want to do something with the HypergraphDB in Java. I'm not very familiar with this language and IDE Netbeans.
I followed steps describing the HGDB installation:[Link to tutorial](http://www.hypergraphdb.org/learn?page=IntroInstall&project=hypergraphdb)
Now I want to write an example in Java (using NetbeansIDE).

So I created new project, added refferences to the downloaded libraries. OK, now I'm able to import packages with HGDB. The only thing I have in my `main` method is `HyperGraph HG = new HyperGraph(dbLocation);`. This code compiles. But get following runtime error:

```
    run:
checkpoint kbytes:0
checkpoint minutes:0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is 1 existing transaction opened against the Environment.
Aborting open transactions ...
aborting <Transaction id="28">
    at com.sleepycat.je.Environment.close(Environment.java:383)
    at org.hypergraphdb.storage.bje.BJEStorageImplementation.shutdown(BJEStorageImplementation.java:178)
    at org.hypergraphdb.HGStore.close(HGStore.java:355)
    at org.hypergraphdb.HyperGraph.open(HyperGraph.java:392)
    at org.hypergraphdb.HyperGraph.open(HyperGraph.java:213)
    at org.hypergraphdb.HyperGraph.<init>(HyperGraph.java:200)
    at hgdbtest.HgdbTest.main(HgdbTest.java:16)
Exception in thread "main" org.hypergraphdb.HGException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hypergraphdb.storage.bje.LinkBinding.objectToEntry(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/sleepycat/je/DatabaseEntry;)V
    at org.hypergraphdb.HyperGraph.open(HyperGraph.java:395)
    at org.hypergraphdb.HyperGraph.open(HyperGraph.java:213)
    at org.hypergraphdb.HyperGraph.<init>(HyperGraph.java:200)
    at hgdbtest.HgdbTest.main(HgdbTest.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hypergraphdb.storage.bje.LinkBinding.objectToEntry(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/sleepycat/je/DatabaseEntry;)V
    at org.hypergraphdb.storage.bje.BJEStorageImplementation.store(BJEStorageImplementation.java:234)
    at org.hypergraphdb.HGStore.store(HGStore.java:119)
    at org.hypergraphdb.HGTypeSystem.addPrimitiveTypeToStore(HGTypeSystem.java:185)
    at org.hypergraphdb.HGTypeSystem.bootstrap(HGTypeSystem.java:234)
    at org.hypergraphdb.HyperGraph.open(HyperGraph.java:355)
    ... 3 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

I guess it's caused by the native API of the BerkeleyDB.

According to the tutorial, in project options I supply the `-Djava.library.path=$HGDB_ROOT/lib/native/$PLATFORM` argument on Run card as a VM Option. Instead of the system variables I use full-path to the libraries.
My OS in Windows7. I'm not sure about using slashes or backslashes or double-backslashes as a path-separator.?

So a simply question is: how have I to set up the IDE for using the HypergraphDB?

Thank you for advices!

Comment: Did you add all three required libraries: hgbdbje-1.3.jar, hgdb-1.3.jar, je-5.0.34.jar??

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the stack trace, you are using the latest version of HyperGraphDB. In that version, the native API is not used. Rather, it's Java only libraries. You have to include the BerkeleyDB Java Edition 5.0.34 jar in your runtime classpath. You can get it either from the Oracle http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html or from the HyperGraphDB Maven repository: http://hypergraphdb.org/maven/org/hypergraphdb/hgbdbje/1.2/hgbdbje-1.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it (by accident) by fixing the order of the libraries on which you're HyperGraphDB application relies on. The library **je-[version].jar** has to be ABOVE (and hence to be referenced before) **db-[version].jar**

Comment: Highly doubt this could be an issue, if order of libraries included had any weight on compilation errors I cannot imagine projects with 40-80 libraries what a mess would become!